# Is it possible to delay-load PRISM / Xamarin Forms components that aren't immediately needed?

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism, appdelegate, syncfusion, lazy-initialization

I have the following AppDelegate which takes quite some time to load:

```
      Syncfusion.ListView.XForms.iOS.SfListViewRenderer.Init();
        new Syncfusion.SfNumericUpDown.XForms.iOS.SfNumericUpDownRenderer();
        Syncfusion.SfCarousel.XForms.iOS.SfCarouselRenderer.Init();
        Syncfusion.XForms.iOS.Buttons.SfSegmentedControlRenderer.Init();
        Syncfusion.XForms.iOS.Buttons.SfCheckBoxRenderer.Init();

        new Syncfusion.XForms.iOS.ComboBox.SfComboBoxRenderer();
        //Syncfusion.XForms.iOS.TabView.SfTabViewRenderer.Init();
        new Syncfusion.SfRotator.XForms.iOS.SfRotatorRenderer();
        new Syncfusion.SfRating.XForms.iOS.SfRatingRenderer();
        new Syncfusion.SfBusyIndicator.XForms.iOS.SfBusyIndicatorRenderer();
```

- What options should I consider when I know some of these components aren't needed for the main screen, but for subscreens?
- I am using PRISM, and it appears that every tab is pre-loaded immediately before allowing display or interaction with the end user.  What can I do to delay the pre-rendering that the Prism TabView does prior to showing the interface?
- Should I use `Lazy<T>`?  What is the right approach?
- Should I move these components to another initialization section?

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of ways you could ultimately achieve this, and it all depends on what your real goals are.

If your goal is to ensure that you get to a Xamarin.Forms Page as fast as possible so that you have some sort of activity indicator, that in essence says to the user, "it's ok I haven't frozen, we're just doing some stuff to get ready for you", then you might try creating a "SpashScreen" page where you do additional loading. The setup might look something like the following:

```
public partial class AppDelegate : FormsApplicationDelegate
    {
        public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
            LoadApplication(new App(new iOSInitializer()));

            return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
        }
    }
}

public class iOSInitializer : IPlatformInitializer, IPlatformFinalizer
{
    public void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
    {
        containerRegistry.RegisterInstance<IPlatformFinalizer>(this);
    }

    public void Finalize()
    {
        new Syncfusion.SfNumericUpDown.XForms.iOS.SfNumericUpDownRenderer();
        Syncfusion.SfCarousel.XForms.iOS.SfCarouselRenderer.Init();
        Syncfusion.XForms.iOS.Buttons.SfSegmentedControlRenderer.Init();
        Syncfusion.XForms.iOS.Buttons.SfCheckBoxRenderer.Init();
    }
}

public class App : PrismApplication
{
    protected override async void OnInitialized()
    {
        await NavigationService.NavigateAsync("SplashScreen");
    }
}

public class SplashScreenViewModel : INavigationAware
{
    private IPlatformFinalizer _platformFinalizer { get; }
    private INavigationService _navigationService { get; }

    public SplashScreenViewModel(INavigationService navigationService, IPlatformFinalizer platformFinalizer)
    {
        _navigationService = navigationService;
        _platformFinalizer = platformFinalizer;
    }

    public async void OnNavigatedTo(INavigationParameters navigationParameters)
    {
        _platformFinalizer.Finalize();
        await _navigationService.NavigateAsync("/MainPage");
    }
}
```

If you're working with Modules you could take a similar approach though any Modules that would initialize at Startup would still be making that call to Init the renderers before you've set a Page to navigate to. That said, working with Modules does give you a number of benefits here as you only ever would have to initialize things that the app actually requires at that point.

All of that said I'd be surprised if you see much in the way of gain as these `Init` calls are typically empty methods only designed to prevent the Linker from linking them out... if you aren't linking or have a linker file you could simply instruct the Linker to leave your Syncfusion and other libraries alone.